# System.Diagnostics.Process pipe (vertical bar) not accepted as argument

Tags: c#, command-line, ffmpeg

I'm trying to execute [this code](http://geekswithblogs.net/PearlFactory/archive/2011/11/23/convert-mp3-to-aacflac-to-aac-or-any-other-combination.aspx) using System.Diagnostics.Process. It works fine in command line. But in C# it's failing on the `|` character.

```
var myProcess = new Process();
var p = new ProcessStartInfo();

var sArgs = " -i emp.mp3 -f wav - | neroAacEnc -ignorelength -q 0.5 -if - -of emp.mp4";
p.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
p.CreateNoWindow = false;
p.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
p.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Arguments = sArgs;

myProcess.StartInfo = p;

myProcess.Start();
myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

It gives the following error:

> Unable to find a suitable output format for '|': Invalid argument

I've looked around on stackoverflow and found the following hint but it is also not working:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg.exe");
psi.Arguments = 
    "\"-i emp.mp3 -f wav -\" | \"neroAacEnc -ignorelength -q 0.5 -if - -of emp.mp4\"";
psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;

var process = new Process { StartInfo = psi };

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

gives the following error:

> Unrecognized option 'i emp.mp3 -f wav -' 
>   Failed to set value '|' for option 'i emp.mp3 -f wav -'

Comment: The '|' character is not an argument to ffmpeg, it is a command redirection operator (pipe) in the shell to redirect the output of one program to the input of another.

Comment: do you have any idea how I can redirect the input without the pipe and using C# code?

Comment: You could invoke `cmd.exe` and pass it the full command.

Comment: thanks man, I tried that before but must have missed something as it just works now!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to [Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152602/lee) his comments, the problem has been resolved. Just invoke cmd.exe and pass it the full command:

```
var myProcess = new Process();
var p = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
var sArgs = "/C ffmpeg.exe -i emp.mp3 -f wav - | neroAacEnc -ignorelength -q 0.5 -if - -of emp.mp4";
p.CreateNoWindow = false;
p.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
p.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Arguments = sArgs;
myProcess.StartInfo = p;
myProcess.Start();
myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: If the executable path and/or one or more of the arguments include spaces and need to be enclosed in quotes, remember to enclose the entire command string (the part after /C) in an extra set of quotes (per the help for cmd.exe, "behaviour [for non-trivial command strings that include quotes] is to see if the first character is a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving any text after the last quote character").